# Load React Component dynamically with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel, typescript

I am using laravel for my web application and react as laravel provide default setup itself.

I have installed typescripts in react. Now I  am trying to load my all components dynamically whenever it need by html page.

I have created a fix class to load component and pass the component name as data-component. It was worked perfectly only with react but after when i add TypeScript in this it doesnot working.

It showing error this -

```
ERROR in C:\xampp\htdocs\we-translate\resources\js\LoadComponents.tsx
./resources/js/LoadComponents.tsx
[tsl] ERROR in C:\xampp\htdocs\we-translate\resources\js\LoadComponents.tsx(14,23)
      TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type 'typeof import("C:/xampp/htdocs/we-translate/resources/js/AllComponents")'.

ERROR in C:\xampp\htdocs\we-translate\resources\js\LoadComponents.tsx
./resources/js/LoadComponents.tsx
[tsl] ERROR in C:\xampp\htdocs\we-translate\resources\js\LoadComponents.tsx(14,45)
      TS2339: Property 'component' does not exist on type 'Readonly<{}> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.
```

The class which is load all component is `load_component`. Code in blade file is looks like-

`<div class="load_content" data-component="Hello"></div>`

I have created a file which export all component `AllComponents.tsx`

```
import * as React from "react";

import { Hello } from "./components/Hello";

export {
  Hello
}
```

and created a file `LoadComponents.tsx` which load component as html file hold component name -

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import * as Components from './AllComponents'


export default class LoadComponents extends React.Component {
    constructor(props : any){
      console.log(props);
      console.log(Components);
        super(props);
    }
  render() {
    const Component = Components[this.props.component];
    return Component && <Component {...this.props} />; // *showing error at this line*

  }
}


if(document.querySelectorAll('.load_content')){
    let holders = document.querySelectorAll('.load_content');
    for(let i=0; i < holders.length; i++ ){
        let item: any = holders[i];
        // I am 
        ReactDOM.render(<LoadComponents {...(item.dataset)} />, holders[i]);
    }
}
```

It was perfectly worked when not using typescript in it.